# Cannot reassign a variable in Javascript

Tags: javascript

Below, I reassign trigger to be false and yet when I run this, the button.onclick function will still run even once the trigger variable is false. Not sure why this is happening. Need the function to stop if trigger becomes false.

First, I assign the variable trigger to be true.

I declare that if x is less than 33 that trigger should become false and thus the button.onclick function should not work.

```js
// sets the variables
var n = document.getElementById("number");
var b = document.documentElement.style;
var count = 0;
var x = 0;
var trigger = true;
if (trigger == true) {
  button.onclick = function() {
    count++;
    n.innerHTML = count;
    x = Math.floor(Math.random() * 100);
    if (x < 33) {
      b.backgroundColor = "red";
      trigger = false;
    } else {
      b.backgroundColor = "black";
    }
  }
}
```

```css
.root {
  background-color: black;
}

#number {
  color: white;
  font-size: 100px;
  font-family: Helvetica;
  text-align: center;
  margin: auto;
  border-radius: 1%;
  width: 30%;
  margin-top: 15%;
}

#button {
  display: block;
  background-color: white;
  outline: none;
  font-size: 15px;
  font-weight: bolder;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  padding: 10px 15px 10px 15px;
  border-radius: 5%;
  margin: auto;
  margin-top: 50px;
  font-family: Helvetica;
}

#rnum {
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 15px;
  color: white;
  margin-top: 50px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lobster" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">

<div id="number" type="number"> 0 </div>
<div> <button id="button"> Click </button> </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Since `trigger` is `true` the event handler is attached with the button element, afterwards it plays no role in execution as code in the event handler doesn't evaluate the condition `if (trigger == true)`.

You need to move the `if` condition inside the event handler

```
button.onclick = function () {
  if (trigger == true) { //Moved statement in event handler
    count ++;
    n.innerHTML = count;
    x = Math.floor(Math.random()*100);
    if (x < 33) {
      b.backgroundColor = "red";
      trigger = false;
    } else {
      b.backgroundColor = "black";
    }
  }
}
```

```js
// sets the variables
var n = document.getElementById("number");
var b = document.documentElement.style;
var count = 0;
var x = 0;
var trigger = true;

button.onclick = function() {
  if (trigger == true) {
    count++;
    n.innerHTML = count;
    x = Math.floor(Math.random() * 100);
    if (x < 33) {
      b.backgroundColor = "red";
      trigger = false;
    } else {
      b.backgroundColor = "black";
    }
  }
}
```

```css
.root {
  background-color: black;
}

#number {
  color: white;
  font-size: 100px;
  font-family: Helvetica;
  text-align: center;
  margin: auto;
  border-radius: 1%;
  width: 30%;
  margin-top: 15%;
}

#button {
  display: block;
  background-color: white;
  outline: none;
  font-size: 15px;
  font-weight: bolder;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  padding: 10px 15px 10px 15px;
  border-radius: 5%;
  margin: auto;
  margin-top: 50px;
  font-family: Helvetica;
}

#rnum {
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 15px;
  color: white;
  margin-top: 50px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lobster" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">

<div id="number" type="number"> 0 </div>
<div> <button id="button"> Click </button> </div>
```

Comment: Oh I see. So my code was basically saying if trigger is true then attach the event handler (onclick) to the element (button).